# Using an array within a switch / case function in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add a picker view to my existing app.  However, I have hit a snag.  I am still new to Swift, I am not sure how to describe this, but hopefully you will understand enough of the below to ask the appropriate question to solve this.

The error message I get is "fatal error: Index out of range" from the line:

```
cell.txtField_PickData.text = self.arrayTemprature[indexPath.row].valueForKey("tempValue") as? String
```

The myTitleArry is equal to two inputs "Air Temperature" or "Water temperature"

Here is the portion of code around this error. If more code is needed to help identify the issue, happy to provide:

```
import UIKit

class DiveDetailsViewController: UITableViewController, LocationDelegate, ItemDataSelectedProtocol, UITextFieldDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource , UIPickerViewDelegate
{

let numberOfComponents: Int             = 2
let temperatureComponentRows: Int       = 131
let temperatureSymbolComponentRows: Int = 2

let Fahrenheit: String                  = "F"
let Celsius: String                     = "C"
let minDegrees                          = -10
let maxDegrees                          = 120

private var degrees = [Int]()

var temperature: Int                    = 26    // our default temperature
var temperatureType: String             = "C"   // our default type is Farenheit


//   let myTitleArray = ["Air temperature" , "Water temperature"]
var pickerView : UIPickerView!
var pickerViewFarCel : UIPickerView!


var dictTemprature = [String : String]()

var arrayTemprature = [AnyObject]()

var tempIndex = 0
var tempSymbolIndex = 0

var arraySymbol = ["C" , "F"]

var tempratureOfAir : String = ""
var tempratureOfWater : String = ""



private typealias ItemDefaults = [ItemTypes : String]

private let NumberOfSections: Int                       = 7
private let NumberOfRowsInSection0: Int                 = 2
private let NumberOfRowsInSection1: Int                 = 7
private let NumberOfRowsInSection2: Int                 = 4
private let NumberOfRowsInSection3: Int                 = 6
private let NumberOfRowsInSection4: Int                 = 3
private let NumberOfRowsInSection5: Int                 = 4
private let NumberOfRowsInSection6: Int                 = 1


//
//  Section 0 Cells
//
private let DiveNumberIndex: NSIndexPath                = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)  

private let DiveNameIndex: NSIndexPath                  = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)

 //  Section 1 Cells

private let DiveWaterIndex: NSIndexPath                 = NSIndexPath(forRow:  0, inSection: 1)
private let DiveVisibilityIndex: NSIndexPath            = NSIndexPath(forRow:  1, inSection: 1)
private let DiveCurrentsIndex: NSIndexPath              = NSIndexPath(forRow:  2, inSection: 1)
private let AirTempPickerIndex: NSIndexPath             = NSIndexPath(forRow:  3, inSection: 1)
private let WaterTempPickerIndex: NSIndexPath           = NSIndexPath(forRow:  4, inSection: 1)
private let DiveWeatherIndex: NSIndexPath               = NSIndexPath(forRow:  5, inSection: 1)
private let DiveSurfaceIndex: NSIndexPath               = NSIndexPath(forRow:  6, inSection: 1)


//  Section 2 Cells

private let DiveLocationIndex: NSIndexPath              = NSIndexPath(forRow:  0, inSection: 2)
private let DiveBodyOfWaterIndex: NSIndexPath           = NSIndexPath(forRow:  1, inSection: 2)
private let DiveCityIndex: NSIndexPath                  = NSIndexPath(forRow:  2, inSection: 2)
private let DiveCountryIndex: NSIndexPath               = NSIndexPath(forRow:  3, inSection: 2)

//  Section 3 Cells

private let DiveCircuitIndex: NSIndexPath               = NSIndexPath(forRow:  0, inSection: 3)
private let DiveStartingPressureIndex: NSIndexPath      = NSIndexPath(forRow:  1, inSection: 3)
private let DiveEndingPressureIndex: NSIndexPath        = NSIndexPath(forRow:  2, inSection: 3)
private let DiveWeightIndex: NSIndexPath                = NSIndexPath(forRow:  3, inSection: 3)
private let DiveDiveSuitIndex: NSIndexPath              = NSIndexPath(forRow:  4, inSection: 3)
private let DiveEquipmentIndex: NSIndexPath             = NSIndexPath(forRow:  5, inSection: 3)

//  Section 4 Cells

private let DiveEntryTypeIndex: NSIndexPath             = NSIndexPath(forRow:  0, inSection: 4)
private let DiveDiveTypeIndex: NSIndexPath              = NSIndexPath(forRow:  1, inSection: 4)
private let DiveRatingIndex: NSIndexPath                = NSIndexPath(forRow:  2, inSection: 4)

//  Section 5 Cells

private let DiveDiveMasterIndex: NSIndexPath             = NSIndexPath(forRow:  0, inSection: 5)
private let DiveDiveBoatOperatorIndex: NSIndexPath       = NSIndexPath(forRow:  1, inSection: 5)
private let DiveDiveCenterIndex: NSIndexPath             = NSIndexPath(forRow:  2, inSection: 5)
private let DiveTripOperatorIndex: NSIndexPath           = NSIndexPath(forRow:  3, inSection: 5)

//  Section 6 Cells

private let DiveNotesIndex: NSIndexPath                 = NSIndexPath(forRow:  0, inSection: 6)



private let location: Location              = Location()
private var isSelected: Bool                = false
private var defaultValues: ItemDefaults     = ItemDefaults()
private var selectedItemType: ItemTypes     = ItemTypes.None
private var longitude: Double               = 0.0
private var latitude: Double                = 0.0


var diveModel: DiveModel = DiveModel()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Array of the Degree :

    for i in self.minDegrees ..< self.maxDegrees+1{
        self.degrees.append(i)
    }
    print(self.degrees)

    // Array of Table

    self.dictTemprature = ["tempValue" : "" , "tempSymbol" : ""]

    arrayTemprature = [self.dictTemprature , self.dictTemprature]

    print(arrayTemprature)

    print(self.arrayTemprature[0].valueForKey("tempValue"))


    //
    self.registerCustomTableViewCells()

    self.defaultValues =  self.getDefaultValues()

    print(self.diveModel)

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    location.delegate = self
    location.start()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    switch indexPath
    {

    case DiveNumberIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveNumberCell)
        (cell as! DiveNumberTableViewCell).textField.placeholder = Strings.DiveNumber.localized
        //I realize this will be autoentered, but needs to be displayed


    case DiveNameIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveSiteCell)
        (cell as! DiveSiteTableViewCell).textField.placeholder = Strings.Name.localized
        //This will need to be the data entered from the previous screen and not editable


    case AirTempPickerIndex:

        let cell : AirTemperatureTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AirTemperatureCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AirTemperatureTableViewCell
        cell.txtField_PickData.tag    =  indexPath.row
        cell.textField_TempSymbol.tag =  indexPath.row

        cell.txtField_PickData.placeholder = "Air"

        cell.textField_TempSymbol.placeholder = ""
        cell.txtField_PickData.text = self.arrayTemprature[indexPath.row].valueForKey("tempValue") as? String
        cell.textField_TempSymbol.text = self.arrayTemprature[indexPath.row].valueForKey("tempSymbol") as? String
        return cell


    case WaterTempPickerIndex:

        let cell : WaterTemperatureTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WaterTemperatureCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WaterTemperatureTableViewCell
        cell.txtField_PickData.tag    =  indexPath.row
        cell.textField_TempSymbol.tag =  indexPath.row

        cell.txtField_PickData.placeholder = "Water"

        cell.textField_TempSymbol.placeholder = ""
        cell.txtField_PickData.text = self.arrayTemprature[indexPath.row].valueForKey("tempValue") as? String
        cell.textField_TempSymbol.text = self.arrayTemprature[indexPath.row].valueForKey("tempSymbol") as? String
        return cell


    case DiveLocationIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.LocationCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.Location.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = String(format: "%f, %f", self.latitude, self.longitude)

    case DiveWeatherIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.Weather.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = self.defaultValues[ItemTypes.Weather]

    case DiveVisibilityIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.Visibility.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = self.defaultValues[ItemTypes.Visibility]

    case DiveEntryTypeIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.EntryType.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = self.defaultValues[ItemTypes.EntryType]

    case DiveWaterIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.Water.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = self.defaultValues[ItemTypes.Water]

    case DiveDiveSuitIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.DiveSuit.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = self.defaultValues[ItemTypes.DiveSuit]

    case DiveNotesIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveNoteCell)

    case DiveRatingIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.Rating.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ""

    case DiveCurrentsIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.Currents.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = self.defaultValues[ItemTypes.Currents]

    case DiveSurfaceIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.Surface.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = self.defaultValues[ItemTypes.Surface]

    case DiveBodyOfWaterIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.BodyOfWater.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ""

    case DiveCityIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.City.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ""

    case DiveCountryIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.Country.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ""

    case DiveCircuitIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.Circuit.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = self.defaultValues[ItemTypes.Circuit]

    case DiveStartingPressureIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.StartingTankUsageCell)
        (cell as! StartingTankUsageCell).startingPressureTextField.placeholder = Strings.Start.localized

    case DiveEndingPressureIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.EndingTankUsageCell)
        (cell as! EndingTankUsageCell).textField.placeholder = Strings.Finish.localized

    case DiveDiveMasterIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.DiveMaster.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ""

    case DiveWeightIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.WeightsCell)
        (cell as! WeightsTableViewCell).textField.placeholder = Strings.Weight.localized

    case DiveEquipmentIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.Equipment.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ""

    case DiveDiveTypeIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.DiveType.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = self.defaultValues[ItemTypes.DiveType]

    case DiveDiveBoatOperatorIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.BoatOperator.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ""

    case DiveDiveCenterIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.DiveCenter.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ""

    case DiveTripOperatorIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveItemCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = Strings.TripOperator.localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ""


    default:
        cell = nil
    }


    return cell
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return self.NumberOfSections
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if section == 0
    {
        return self.NumberOfRowsInSection0
    }
    else if section == 1
    {
        return self.NumberOfRowsInSection1
    }
    else if section == 2
    {
        return self.NumberOfRowsInSection2
    }
    else if section == 3
    {
        return self.NumberOfRowsInSection3
    }
    else if section == 4
    {
        return self.NumberOfRowsInSection4
    }
    else if section == 5
    {
        return self.NumberOfRowsInSection5
    }
    else if section == 6
    {
        return self.NumberOfRowsInSection6
    }
    else
    {
        return 0
    }
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath?
{
    //
    //  It the row that is going to be selected is of an item type, then we save off the 
    //  selectedItemType so it can be used during the segue.
    //
    switch indexPath
    {
    case DiveWeatherIndex:
        self.selectedItemType = ItemTypes.Weather

    case DiveVisibilityIndex:
        self.selectedItemType = ItemTypes.Visibility

    case DiveEntryTypeIndex:
        self.selectedItemType = ItemTypes.EntryType

    case DiveWaterIndex:
        self.selectedItemType = ItemTypes.Water

    case DiveDiveSuitIndex:
        self.selectedItemType = ItemTypes.DiveSuit

    case DiveDiveTypeIndex:
        self.selectedItemType = ItemTypes.DiveType

    case DiveCurrentsIndex:
        self.selectedItemType = ItemTypes.Currents

    case DiveSurfaceIndex:
        self.selectedItemType = ItemTypes.Surface

    case DiveCircuitIndex:
        self.selectedItemType = ItemTypes.Circuit

    default:
        self.selectedItemType = ItemTypes.None
    }

    return indexPath
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if cell is DiveEditTableViewCell
    {
        (cell as! DiveEditTableViewCell).textField.userInteractionEnabled = true
        (cell as! DiveEditTableViewCell).textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if cell is DiveNoteTableViewCell
    {
        (cell as! DiveNoteTableViewCell).textView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        (cell as! DiveNoteTableViewCell).textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if cell is StartingTankUsageCell
    {
        (cell as! StartingTankUsageCell).startingPressureTextField.userInteractionEnabled = true
        (cell as! StartingTankUsageCell).startingPressureTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if cell is EndingTankUsageCell
    {
        (cell as! EndingTankUsageCell).textField.userInteractionEnabled = true
        (cell as! EndingTankUsageCell).textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if cell is WeightsTableViewCell
    {
        (cell as! WeightsTableViewCell).textField.userInteractionEnabled = true
        (cell as! WeightsTableViewCell).textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if cell is DiveEditTableViewCell
    {
        (cell as! DiveEditTableViewCell).textField.userInteractionEnabled = false
        (cell as! DiveEditTableViewCell).textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else if cell is DiveNoteTableViewCell
    {
        (cell as! DiveNoteTableViewCell).textView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        (cell as! DiveNoteTableViewCell).textView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else if cell is StartingTankUsageCell
    {
        (cell as! StartingTankUsageCell).startingPressureTextField.userInteractionEnabled = false
        (cell as! StartingTankUsageCell).startingPressureTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if cell is EndingTankUsageCell
    {
        (cell as! EndingTankUsageCell).textField.userInteractionEnabled = false
        (cell as! EndingTankUsageCell).textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if cell is WeightsTableViewCell
    {
        (cell as! WeightsTableViewCell).textField.userInteractionEnabled = false
        (cell as! WeightsTableViewCell).textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    var height = tableView.rowHeight


    if indexPath == self.DiveNotesIndex
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveNoteCell)
        height = CGFloat((cell?.bounds.size.height)!)
    }

    return height
}

func fahToCel(tempInF:Double) ->Double {
    let celsius = (tempInF - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0)
    return celsius as Double
}

func celToFah(tempInC:Double) ->Double {
    let fahrenheit = (tempInC * 9.0/5.0) + 32.0
    return fahrenheit as Double
}


func pickerFarCal(textField : UITextField){

    self.tempSymbolIndex = 0

    pickerViewFarCel = UIPickerView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 216))
    pickerViewFarCel.delegate = self
    pickerViewFarCel.dataSource = self
    pickerViewFarCel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textField.inputView = pickerViewFarCel
    pickerViewFarCel.tag =  textField.tag

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    // Adds the buttons

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(DiveDetailsViewController.doneClickSymbol))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(DiveDetailsViewController.cancelClickSymbol))
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}

func doneClickSymbol(){

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    print(self.arraySymbol[tempSymbolIndex])

    if self.arrayTemprature[pickerViewFarCel.tag].valueForKey("tempValue") as! String == ""{
        print("Not Convert")
    }else if self.arrayTemprature[pickerViewFarCel.tag].valueForKey("tempSymbol") as! String == self.arraySymbol[tempSymbolIndex]{
        print("Not Convert")
    }else{
        print("Convert")

        if self.arraySymbol[tempSymbolIndex] == "C"{
            let value = Double(self.arrayTemprature[pickerViewFarCel.tag].valueForKey("tempValue") as! String)
            let convertedValue = self.fahToCel(value!)
            let myValue = String(format: "%.1f", convertedValue)
            self.dictTemprature["tempValue"] = myValue
            self.dictTemprature["tempSymbol"] = self.arraySymbol[tempSymbolIndex]
        }else{
            let value = Double(self.arrayTemprature[pickerViewFarCel.tag].valueForKey("tempValue") as! String)
            let convertedValue = self.celToFah(value!)
            let myValue = String(format: "%.1f", convertedValue)
            self.dictTemprature["tempValue"] = myValue
            self.dictTemprature["tempSymbol"] = self.arraySymbol[tempSymbolIndex]
        }
        self.arrayTemprature[pickerViewFarCel.tag] = self.dictTemprature

        tableView.reloadData()

    }

}
func cancelClickSymbol(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}


// PickerView

func pickerViewTemprature(textField : UITextField){

    // Index

    self.tempSymbolIndex = 0
    self.tempIndex = 276

    pickerView = UIPickerView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 216))
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textField.inputView = pickerView
    pickerView.tag = textField.tag
    pickerView.selectRow(276, inComponent: 0, animated: true)


    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    // Adds the buttons


    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(DiveDetailsViewController.doneClickMaterial))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(DiveDetailsViewController.cancelClickMaterial))
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar


}

func doneClickMaterial(){

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    self.dictTemprature["tempValue"] = "\(self.degrees[tempIndex])"
    self.dictTemprature["tempSymbol"] = self.arraySymbol[tempSymbolIndex]
    self.arrayTemprature[pickerView.tag] = self.dictTemprature

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
func cancelClickMaterial(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

// MARK: delegate

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    if (pickerViewFarCel != nil){
        return 1
    }else{
        return 2
    }

}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat{

    return 100

}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if (pickerViewFarCel != nil){
        return self.temperatureSymbolComponentRows
    }else{
        if component == 0{
            return self.degrees.count
        }
        else{
            return self.temperatureSymbolComponentRows
        }

    }

}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if (pickerViewFarCel != nil){
        return self.arraySymbol[row]
    }else{
        if component == 0 {
            return "\(self.degrees[row])"
        } else {
            return self.arraySymbol[row]
        }
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if (pickerViewFarCel != nil){
        tempSymbolIndex = row
    }else{
        if component == 0 {
            tempIndex = row
        } else {
            tempSymbolIndex = row
        }

    }

}
```

UPDATE:
I removed the title array and simply added another dynamic cell and separated the data that drives the two.

The Index out of range disappears for the title, but now creates the same error for the row:
    cell.txtField_PickData.text = self.arrayTemprature[indexPath.row].valueForKey("tempValue") as? String

This feature does not require an extra row, so now I am wondering if the error is in the way the array gathers its data.

I have added most all of the code.  Had to reduce some to get within the 30k limit.

Comment: The issue is simply that `myTitleArray` doesn't have an item associated with the `indexPath.row` value. So look at what the row number is, and then look at how many items you have in that array. If that array only has two items, then the row number can only be zero or one (given how that line is currently written, anyway).

Comment: Again, to diagnose, you have to share (a) what value `indexPath.row` was; and (b) what the `arrayTemprature` [sic] contained. It would appear that `row` exceeded the number of items in that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue was caused to a wrong `numberOfRowsInSection` implementation.

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:):

> Tells the data source to return the number of rows in a given section
>   of a table view.

Take care about this method and make all changes it need to bring all possible variations of your datasource.

Here you can see an example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = self. myTitleArray?.count as Int {
        return (count)
    } else {
        //myTitleArray is nil, so just return 0
        return 0
    }
}
```

**Update**: (after your new edit to the main question)

Seems there is an error:
Section 1 Cells have 6 elements but you have declare:

```
private let NumberOfRowsInSection1: Int                 = 5
```

**More details** about your issue:

Your problem is typical: "Index out of range", what does it mean? your array, in this case self.arrayTemprature don't have the index required during the statement so for example if you have an array of 3 elements and you request the 4th element this is the error you will see. But this error happened also when you don't initialize your array and pretend to request an inexsistent element (your array is nil and you want always the 4th element: index out of range). So , check your self.arrayTemprature from the start of it's declaration, initialization, use breakpoint and check why you got this error.

Comment: Alessandro, now I have the following.  As there are 7 rows in this section, not sure how to implement the above.  I currently have:        

    else if section == 1
            {
              return self.NumberOfRowsInSection1
            }

Comment: Could you add to your question both numberOfRowInSection and numberOfSections methods?

Comment: Yes, I was trying different numbers.  without the tempPicker, there are 5 rows.  My idea (just before pasting code) was to set the 5 and add the myTitleArray.count to the # of rows in section.

Comment: The original number was 6.  I have tried 6 + 1; 5 + myTitleArray.count.    .   FYI, I have assigned this to a single dynamic cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116308/discussion-between-david-sanford-and-alessandro-ornano).